# parallelogram and using determinants find tha area

Tags: determinant

Show that the point $A(0,0)$, $B(2,5)$, $C(7,-3)$, $D(9,2)$ are vertices of the parallelogram and using determinants to find its area.

Comment: If you plot the points on a Cartesian plane and find the slope of the opposite sides to be equal, meaning that the lines are parallel, then you can prove it is a parallelogram.

Comment: Then create a matrix whose columns are vectors representing the two non-parallel sides and compute its determinant.

Answer (score 2):

Note that $A$, $B$, $C$, $D$ are not in correct order.

Since $A+D=B+C=(9,2)$, $AD$ and $BC$ bisect each other.

Hence, $ABDC$ is a parallelogram.

$$\text{Area of }ABDC =
  \left| \vec{AB} \times \vec{AC} \right|$$